# Euler-style sum of reciprocals of squares of roots of a function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

If I understand correctly, historically, Euler proved that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}
$$
by considering on the one hand taylor expansion of
$$
\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1-\frac{x^2}{6} + \dots
$$
and on the other hand it's expression as a product of $(1-x/\textrm{k-th root})$
$$
\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=\dots \left(1-\frac{x}{2\pi}\right) \left(1-\frac{x}{\pi}\right) \left(1+\frac{x}{\pi}\right) \left(1+\frac{x}{2\pi}\right) \dots = \dots \left(1-\frac{x^2}{(\pi)^2}\right) \left(1-\frac{x^2}{(2\pi)^2}\right) = 1 - x^2\left(1+\frac{1}{(\pi)^2}+\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}+\dots\right) + \dots
$$

While this is not rigorous enough by today's standards, I tried to generalize this result. Consider a function $f(x)$ such that

1. $f(0)=1$
2. $f(-x)=f(x)$
3. $f''(0)<0$
4. $f(x)$ has infinitely many positive roots $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ with corresponding multiplicities $m_k$. By pt.2 it also has infinitely many negative roots $-x_k$ with same multiplicities.

Then following the same steps one can arrive at
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{m_k}{x_k^2} = \frac12 |f''(0)|
$$

I wonder, if this is indeed a correct result? Are there other relations between zeros of certain types of functions and their derivatives?

Comment: The statement isn't true in general. Let's say you have a $f(x)$ that works. Consider the function $g(x) = f(x) e^{-x^2}$.You will find that $g(x)$ satisfies the same condition, having same LHS but with a different value in RHS ($\frac12|g''(0)| = \frac12\left(|f''(0)| + 1\right)$.

Comment: @achillehui you're right, thanks. I wonder though if it is correct for some types of functions, or perhaps it's a by-product of another general theorem

Comment: I would look up the notion of finite order entire function and its Hadamard product to understand what's going on; for example, if one has some normal convergence of the infinite product (or a symmetric version like in the sine case - eg if $\sum {m_k/x_k^2}$ converges), one can construct an entire function for which the relation is true; but then as noted, one can multiply it by exponentials and keep same zeroes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function